# How can I preserve the value of an <input> element when dragging and dropping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage in which I have two `<div>`s. Both elements are draggable; when one is dropped over the other, the positions are switched. Currently, the way the JS works is to actually switch the `innerHtml` property of both elements (meaning we get the `innerHtml` of the dragged element, the `innerHtml` of the drop zone element, and set both properties to the other element's value).

This works fine for switching the element's position. However, when the switch happens, data that is in `<input>` elements in both `<div>`s gets removed. How do I preserve this data when dragging and dropping?

I've tried the following:

- Switching the DOM node reference itself, instead of the `innerHtml` property
- Using `cloneNode()` and `$.clone()`
- Getting the `value` property, in addition to `innerHtml`, and switching that too. This was rejected because it would be impractical due to the way the code is structured.

I have JQuery available, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.detach()` and `.append()` methods.

To move a div on the DOM, call `$(div).detach();` to remove it from its current location, and then call `$(newParent).append(div);` to append it to its new location.

I'm assuming both `div` and `newParent` are either the elements themselves, or a selector to retrieve the correct element.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10223932/1198896).